# Remove User Duplicate From Array String

Tags: java, arrays, string, boolean, duplicates

I am trying to create a program that accepts as many Social Security Numbers as the user wants to input. The only restriction is that the numbers must follow the format XXX-XX-XXXX and not accept duplicated entries. This is what I have so far:

**Subclass 2**

```
package SSNServerStorageExpanded;

class SSNArray{
    final String[] ssnNumber;
    int arrayCount;

    public SSNArray(){//defult contructor
        ssnNumber = new String[9999];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public SSNArray(int arraySize){
        ssnNumber = new String[arraySize];
        arrayCount = 0;
    }

    public String[] getSSNNumber(){
        return ssnNumber;
    }

    public int getArrayCount(){
        return arrayCount;
    }

    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
        return SSNFormat.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    }

    public String addSSN(String SSNFormat){
        if(validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
            return ssnNumber[arrayCount++] = SSNFormat;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str = "\nThe Social Security Number(s) you entered is(are):\n";
        for(int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++){/
            str += ssnNumber[x] + "\n";
        }return str;
    }
}
```

**Subclass 1**

```
package SSNServerStorageExpanded;

public class SSNArrayExpanded extends SSNArray{

    public SSNArrayExpanded(){
        super();
    }

    public SSNArrayExpanded(int arraySize){
        super(arraySize);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
        if(super.validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for(int y = 0; y < arrayCount; y++){
                if(ssnNumber[y].equals(ssnNumber[arrayCount])){
                    System.out.println("No duplicates allowed, please try again");
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!duplicate){
                arrayCount++;
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }   
}
```

**Mainclass**

```
package SSNServerStorageExpanded;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSNArrayTestExpanded{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SSNArrayExpanded SSNArrayExpandedObject = new SSNArrayExpanded();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Initiating SSN Server Storage Expanded");
        System.out.println("► Type 'EXIT' at any moment to close the program ◄\n");

        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            System.out.print("Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): ");
            String ssnNumber = input.next();

            if(ssnNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")){
                System.out.print(SSNArrayExpandedObject.validateSSNNumber(ssnNumber));
                return;
            }else if(SSNArrayExpandedObject.validateSSNNumber(ssnNumber)){
                SSNArrayExpandedObject.addSSN(ssnNumber);
            }else{
                System.out.println("!Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with my *public boolean validateSSNNumber* method under Subclass 1 or are there more errors in my code that I am not aware of?

Comment: It seems like `arrayCount` is incremented twice after successful validation. First in `SSNArrayExpanded.validateSSNNumber()`, then in `SSNArray.addSSN()`. Is it correct? Also, doesn't the code `ssnNumber[y].equals(ssnNumber[arrayCount])` produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I'm saying just by looking at the code. So please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass1 can you try this. You need to compare the SSNFormat String entered by user with the array values (you were comparing array values itself). Do not increase the array count here instead do it in addSSN function as you were doing.

```
 @Override
public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
    if(super.validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
        boolean duplicate = false;
        for(int y = 0; y < arrayCount; y++){
            if(ssnNumber[y].equals(SSNFormat)){
                System.out.println("No duplicates allowed, please try again");
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicate){
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

In the SSNArray class use this function for adding SSN number without validating the SSNFormat again.

```
 public String addSSN(String SSNFormat){
        return ssnNumber[arrayCount++] = SSNFormat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a *Set*, which will easily help you to check for any duplicates and will reduce your iteration over array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete Solution, with this you can add N-number of SSN-Number as you want,

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;


class SSNSet{
    final HashSet<String> allSsnNumber = new HashSet<String>();

    public HashSet<String> getAllSsnNumber() {
        return allSsnNumber;
    }

    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
        return SSNFormat.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
    }

    public boolean addSSN(String SSNFormat){
        if(validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
            boolean flag;
            if(allSsnNumber.add(SSNFormat)){
                System.out.println("Added Successfully");
                flag = true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Duplicate Not Allow");
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }else{
            System.out.println("!Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX!");
            return false;
        }
    }

}

public class SSNArrayTestExpanded{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SSNSet SSNArrayExpandedObject = new SSNSet();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Initiating SSN Server Storage Expanded");
        System.out.println(" Type 'EXIT' at any moment to close the program \n");

        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            System.out.print("Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): ");
            String ssnNumber = input.next();

            if(ssnNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")){
                break;
                /*System.out.print(SSNArrayExpandedObject.validateSSNNumber(ssnNumber));
                return;*/
            }else{
                SSNArrayExpandedObject.addSSN(ssnNumber);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("You have entered SSN Numbers are : ");
        System.out.println(SSNArrayExpandedObject.getAllSsnNumber());
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("Program Ended Successfully");
    }
}
```

and Output is :

```
Initiating SSN Server Storage Expanded
 Type 'EXIT' at any moment to close the program 

Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 111-11-1111
Added Successfully
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 222-22-222
!Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX!
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 111-11-1111
Duplicate Not Allow
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 333-33-333
!Please use the format XXX-XX-XXXX!
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): 333-33-3333
Added Successfully
Enter your Social Security Number(XXX-XX-XXXX): EXIT
===============================================
You have entered SSN Numbers are : 
[111-11-1111, 333-33-3333]
===============================================
Program Ended Successfully
```

Comment: @iNoto this code is very easy to understand as well as maintan too.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you go for         LinkedHashSet data structure for storing the ssn number.?, provides easy retrieval and duplicate check in an order of O(1).

```
 final LinkedHashSet<String> ssnNumber;
```

also the code

```
@Override
public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat){
if(super.validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)){
    boolean duplicate = ssnNumber.add(SSNFormat);
    if(duplicate){
       System.out.println("No duplicates allowed, please try again");
       return false;
     }
     return true;
   }
   return false    
}
```

Comment: Hashset `add()` Returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element
Refer Docs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean validateSSNNumber(String SSNFormat) {
            if (super.validateSSNNumber(SSNFormat)) {
               /*
                *Hashset add() - Returns true if this set did not already contain 
                *the specified element.
                *If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
                * unchanged and returns
                */
                boolean duplicate = !uniqueSSNNum.add(SSNFormat);
                return duplicate;
            }
            return false;
        }

    //To use HastSet it's better if you override equals and hashcode 
    //using the fields that you'll use for comparison equality
    // generated using eclipse
    @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + arrayCount;
            result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(ssnNumber);
            return result;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SSNArray other = (SSNArray) obj;
        if (arrayCount != other.arrayCount)
            return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(ssnNumber, other.ssnNumber))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```